# Problem understanding this statement (Kuhn's Annals paper on Subgroup Theorems of Groups)

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

[image]

This is taken from "Subgroup Theorems for Groups Presented by Generators and Relations" by H.W. Kuhn.

I do not really understand the result $H=\{U;\bar{w}r\bar{w}^{-1}=1\}$.

Isn't $\bar{w}r\bar{w}^{-1}=1$ equivalent to $r=1$, and kind of "redundant"? I mean, don't we already know $r=1$ at the beginning? What I understand is that the result of this theorem is that $H$ basically has the same relations as $G$?

I think I am missing something important. Thanks for any enlightenment.

Comment: This formulation misses out most of the details, so I am not surprised that you find it hard to follow. To get a presentation of $H$ you need free generators of $U$, and in the standard Reidemeister-Schreier method,one uses the so-called Schreier generators, which are defined with respect to a system of coset representatives. Then one needs to rewrite the subgroup relators $\bar{w}r\bar{w}^{-1}$ as words in the Schreier generators of $U$. Incidentally, for the result to be true, the system of coset representatives of $U$ in $F$ needs to  be closed under taking prefixes.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks. Is there any good reference to learn the Reidemeister-Schreier method?